# VBA Make a text box in a UserForm Active when the UserForm activates?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How can I make a text box in a UserForm activate when the UserForm activates, so that the user can start typing without having to click in the text box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the TabIndex Property.

Every object on your userform has one, it is the order to which object on the userform are selected when you press the tab button. The object with 0 `TabIndex` will be the active object when a form is loaded also:

So with the `textbox` selected go to the properties pane and look for `Tabindex` set this to 0 and your `textbox` will be selected on open.

[image]

You can also set other `textboxes` index to 1,2,3 and on, so that if the form is being filled out you can simply press tab to go from one text box to another.

Comment: Another note.  The `TabIndex` works on all of the objects on the form, not just the text boxes.

Comment: @ilarson007 Note the second line of my answer where I say `Every object on your userform has one` , feel free to accept my answer as the answer to your questino if you feel it has fully answered it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.SetFocus`. If your textbox's name is `TextBox1`, the following works:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: This one did not work in my code.  The cancel button was still "selected" when the form initialized.

Comment: This probably didn't worked on your case because Initialize and Activate methods aren't the same. The Initialize will work only on the first time after oppening the workbook. UserForm_Activate() will trigger on every Show().