# VBA: Activate text box in non-modal user form

Tags: vba, userform

I have a simple UserForm containing a prompt, TextInput and 2 buttons (ok & cancel). I want the text input box to be activated when the UserForm opens so that the user can type directly in the box, without having to click there with the mouse first of all. I have looked at this answer:
[VBA Make a text box in a UserForm Active when the UserForm activates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104710/vba-make-a-text-box-in-a-userform-active-when-the-userform-activates)
and set the TabIndex of the TextInput to 0.

I have also tried including the line  `NumericBox.SetFocus` to the initialize code. When I set ShowModal to True for the form, both options give the desired outcome, but I really want the form not to be modal. When I set ShowModal to False, the text box is selected (if I hit enter or tab, the selection moves to the OK button (TabIndex 1)), but I can't type straight away in the InputBox - I still need to click with the mouse in the box first.

Is there anyway I can directly type into the input box of a non-modal form as soon as it is opened?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting `SetFocus` of the control you need in the `UserForm_Activate` event

Comment: Thanks, but I have that in both the UserForm_Activate and the UserForm_Initialize events. When the form is set to non-modal, neither seems to help.

Comment: Try removing the `UserForm_Initialize` code, just have the `UserForm_Activate` code

Comment: Unless there is more to your UF, you could consider using an `InputBox` as the text field is active by default and you don't need to stuff about with clunky UF programming.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Ryan: even without the UserForm_Initialize code, using just UserForm_Activate, I get the same results as described above. Samuel: unfortunately the user has a requirement that the excel file can still be used behind the Form (hence the non-modal setting). I have not found how to make an input box non-modal.

I did manage to find a working solution though. Apparently the problem was with the  .show command I had within the UserForm_Initialize - if I delete this, the text field becomes active.